# BroadcastReceiver requires android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions

My Android app needs to be notified about the `BOOT_COMPLETED` event. AndroidManifest.xml contains `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />` and inside `<application>` tag I have the following receiver definition:

```
<receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver" 
          android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Is the `android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"` required? What happens if it is not in place, is there a risk of any application being able to simulate the boot event and invoking my app?

In some examples, [the receiver contains the RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission](http://javatechig.com/android/how-to-start-an-application-at-device-bootup-in-android) and [some the receiver does not](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/SystemEvents/OnBoot/AndroidManifest.xml). Are there API level specific differences?

Comment: Your both link contains `android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"`

Comment: No, the latter, commonsguy example contains `<uses-permission>` tag but not the permission inside `<receiver>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" required?

No, you don't necessarily require the `permission` attribute inside your `<receiver>` declaration for this particular case. From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html):

> `android:permission`
>
> The name of a permission that broadcasters must have to send a message to the broadcast receiver. If this attribute is not set, the
>   permission set by the `<application>` element's `permission` attribute
>   applies to the broadcast receiver. If neither attribute is set, the
>   receiver is not protected by a permission.

So you only need this attribute if you want to make sure that only broadcasters with the authorized permission can send it. However, `BOOT_COMPLETED` is a [protected intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) that can only be sent by the system anyway. It wouldn't hurt to have it there but it is also not necessary.

EDIT:

It *probably* wouldn't hurt to leave the `permission` attribute there but with so many Android versions and device changes out there, I would not include the attribute just to be sure. I don't include it in my apps.

Comment: You are the first one that seems to understand what I am even asking. The linked documentation states exactly what I was looking for: *"This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system."* I guess that has not changed since API level 1?

Comment: Yes, it has been the case since API 1 I believe, at least since API 8 for sure. I added an edit, though, because I don't know for sure if keeping the `permission` attribute wouldn't matter. Since it is not necessary, I think it is safer not to include it.

Comment: The comment *"This is a protected intent that can only be sent by the system."* in Intent.java was added already in 2009: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/854060af30f928c0a65591e9c8314ae17056e6b8%5E%21/core/java/android/content/Intent.java

Answer (score 1):

The Android documentation states: **If you don't request this permission, you will not receive the broadcast at that time.**.

[Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED)

Comment: I do request the permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />`. My question was, do I still require the receiver-specific permission?

Answer (score 0):

Give receiver tag as

```
<receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Make sure also to include the completed boot permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Comment: My question was about the permission in the `<receiver>` tag. I updated to my question to say it more clearly.

Comment: if you will not give <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/> in manifest, then your receiver will not be triggered after boot complete.

Comment: Yes, I know that. My question was about the necessity of permission in the receiver.

Comment: @JuusoOhtonen, check my answer. You don't necessarily need it but it won't hurt to leave it there either.